# How to pass null argument to function that accept :xhp as parameter?

Tags: hacklang, xhp

I have function like this :

```
private static function myfun(
    string $param1,
    :xhp $param2,
  ): :xhp {
    return
      //somethinf
  }
```

I don't want to pass any thing as *param2*. How can I do that ? 
When I try doing like :

```
myfun("Hi",null),
```

It shows me error.

Answer (score 2):

To be able to pass `null` in, your type hint has to allow it. In Hack, this is done by using a [nullable type](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/types/type-system#nullable).

```
private static function myfun(
    string $param1,
    ?:xhp $param2,
): :xhp {
    return
      //somethinf
}
```

The Hack type checker will then also make sure that you check `$param2` is not null before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Does this the trick?

`private static function myfun(
    string $param1,
    :xhp $param2=null,
  ): :xhp {
    return
      //somethinf
  }`